# Generating a tone using DTMF and playing it with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, buffer, avaudioplayer, dtmf

I want to generate a custom DTMF tone and play it on the iPhone.
In order to do so, I have created and allocated a memory buffer with a custom tone (ptr).
Now I want to create a NSData object, initialized with the memory buffer, and pass it to AVAudioPlayer using initWithData:error: instance method.

I wrote the following code, but when I press the button "Play", it crashes.

```
#import "AudioPlayerViewController.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define LENGTH 65535
const int PLAYBACKFREQ = 44100;
const float PI2 = 3.14159265359f * 2;
const int freq1 = 697;
const int freq2 = 1209;



@implementation AudioPlayerViewController

@synthesize playButton, stopButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Allocate space for an array with ten elements of type int.
int *ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
if (ptr == NULL) NSLog(@"Error: Memory buffer could not be allocated.");
else NSLog(@"Allocation succeeded.");

 // The formula for the tone, the content of the buffer.
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) ptr[i] = (sin(i*(PI2*(PLAYBACKFREQ/freq1))) + sin(i*    (PI2*(PLAYBACKFREQ/freq2)))) * 16383;
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:ptr length:SIZE];
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:myData error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
}
-(IBAction) playAudio: (id) sender {
    if (audioPlayer == nil) NSLog([error description]);             
    else [audioPlayer play];
}
-(IBAction) stopAudio: (id) sender { [audioPlayer stop]; }

- (void)dealloc {
    [audioPlayer release];
    [myData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In the documentation, the description of method initWithBytesNoCopy reads:

> A buffer containing data for the new object. bytes must point to a memory block allocated with malloc.

So I have already done this, but it doesn't work.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to expand on "it doesn't work".

Comment: Everything works fine until I press a button "Play" which calls the method playAudio. The button turns blue and Xcode quits my application

Comment: Xcode doesn't "quit your application" - you're probably crashing in some way - what does running under the debugger tell you ?

Comment: Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1993.
2010-08-11 13:27:58.053 gdb-i386-apple-darwin[1995:613] _CFGetHostUUIDString: unable to determine UUID for host. Error: 35
(gdb)

Comment: That's not at all useful.  What does Xcode provide for a stack trace?  What else is printed on the console?  At which line is your application crashing?

Comment: Also, this is an exact duplicate of the question you just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456604/generating-a-dtmf-tone-doesnt-work-application-crashes

Comment: You could just use this: https://github.com/danielgindi/DGToneGenerator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an NSData without copying the data and then you free the data, so NSData now has a dangling pointer. Remove the `free(ptr);` line and try it again. NSData will free the data by itself when it is done with it.

Comment: The second thing that is suspect is that you're giving AVAudioPlayer raw data and it probably doesn't know how to interpret that. Audio files typically have a header that describes the sample rate, the format of the samples, etc. You can fix this by adding a fake header, for example a WAV header which is quite simple. You may need to convert your int's to 16-bit values, though.

Comment: Here is a demo project that shows how to do this: http://github.com/hollance/AVBufferPlayer